# Bigquery.Jobs.Insert - Resumable Upload?

Tags: google-bigquery

The API docs show that you should be able to make insert Jobs resumable, but with no actual ability to receive the resumable upload URI or any examples showing where to set the request as 'resumable'. I am not uploading via a csv/json file, I am streaming bytes in json format straight to the Job.

Some of my code (Java using bigquery v2 api):

```
AbstractInputStreamContent content = new ByteArrayContent("application/json", stream.toByteArray());
            Job insertJob = service.jobs().insert(projectId, loadJob, content).execute();
```

Please explain where to make them resumable. JobConfiguration? Job? AbstractInputStreamContent? service.jobs.insert?

Comment: Where did you read about this resumable? It's first time I see it.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert under parameters, this also mentions that we can append it to the URI but no documentation on how for that either.